# MySQL Error to selecting data

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two column one column associated with another...

Table:base_data

```
id |---name----|-----des
1  | some name1 | The description1
2  | some name2 | The description2
```

Table: photos

```
id |---p_id----|-----photo
1  |     1     | img1s.jpg
2  |     1     | img1w.jpg
3  |     2     | img2.jpg
4  |     2     | img14.jpg
5  |     2     | img15.jpg
```

I want to select all data from table 1(base_data) and one row from associated row from photos: table how can I do that ????

I don't want to select by greatest n per group I want to select all data from the first table and only one row of the second table which matches with the first table row id, just first match not other.

The Result I want...

```
id |---name----|---des----|---p_id----|---photo----|
1  | some name |the des..1|   1       | img1s.jpg|
2  | some name |the des..2|   2       | img2.jpg|
```

Comment: Please modify your result to show how you want the data output to look instead of an array definition.

Comment: This seems to be another [tag:greatest-n-per-group] SQL question. Solutions have been posted many times.

Comment: No, I don't want to select by greatest n per group I want to select all data from the first table and only one row of the second table which matches with the first table row id, just first match not other.

Comment: There is no inherent order to table rows, so your specification of "just first match" isn't really meaningful.  Do you want the photo name with the alphanumerically lowest value?

Comment: No, I want the photo name which p_id row first match with base_data table id.

Comment: look there is two entry in the base_data table, and 5 entry in the photos table, I want just one photo for the one entry of the base_data table match with its id and p_id.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to associate `base_data` with the first photo taken, which should be the one with the lowest `photos.id`. In MySQL, you could write this as follows: Create an intermediate query which gives - for any `p_id` - the corresponding record with the lowest `id`. Then, left join `base_data` with this intermediate query result. Hope there are not to many typos in it :-) :

```
select b.id, p2.photo
from base_data b left join
   (select p.photo, p.p_id, min(id) from photos p group by p.p_id) p2 on b.id = p2.p_id
```

Comment: but how can I just select id from the base_data table and photo from the photos table ????

Answer (score 0):

If you want the alphanumerically lowest photo name, in MySQL you can do this:

```
select
    t1.*,
    t2.photo
from
    base_data as t1
    left join (
        select
            p_id,
            min(photo) as photo
        from
            photos
        group by
            p_id
        ) as t2 on t2.p_id = t1.id;
```

Comment: look there is two entry in the base_data table, and 5 entry in the photos table, I want just one photo for the one entry of the base_data table match with its id and p_id.